# SQL to CSV in a php script, multiple 'total' rows for groups

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a php script that runs a MySQL query and writes the results to a CSV, which is working successfully but I also want my csv to have a row for each 'group' of agents that sums up their numbers.

The current output looks like this:

[image]

So you can see they are ordered by extension here. So I would want my output, for 7200 for example, to be:

```
7200 totals: 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2
```

Basically just adding a row that sums up the count of x's for each extension, which would mean I would have about 13 rows because I have 13 agent extensions on the full report.

I'm not sure if I can do this in some way with SQL, writing to the CSV, or just do this in PHP itself. Whichever is best and more plausible.

Here's the PHP variable for the Query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn2,
"SELECT  firstn
, lastn
, extension
, Recieved
, RecievedKnown
, Outbound
, outboundKnown
, Missed
, MissedKnown
, CallingNumber
, CalledNumber
, starttime
, endtime
  , duration
, HOLDTIMESECS
, TERMINATIONREASONCODE

    FROM (
  SELECT firstn
   , lastn
   , c.extension
   ,CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 2 AND ANSWERED = 1 THEN 'x' ELSE '' END AS Recieved
   , case when LEGTYPE1 = 2 and answered = 1 and CALLINGPARTYNO = k.phone_number then 'x' ELSE '' end as RecievedKnown
   , CASE WHEN ANSWERED = 1 AND LEGTYPE1 = 1 then 'x' ELSE '' end  AS Outbound
   , case when LEGTYPE1 = 1 and FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO = k.phone_number then 'x' ELSE '' end as outboundKnown
   , case when Answered = 0 then 'x' ELSE '' end as Missed
   , case when ANSWERED = 0 and CALLINGPARTYNO = k.phone_number then 'x' ELSE '' end as MissedKnown
   , a.CALLINGPARTYNO AS CallingNumber
   , a.FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO AS CalledNumber
   , b.starttime as starttime
   , b.endtime as endtime
   , b.duration
   , a.holdtimesecs
   , a.terminationreasoncode

  FROM test.session a
  INNER JOIN test.callsummary b ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
  right join test2.users c on a.callingpartyno = c.extension or a.finallycalledpartyno = c.extension
  LEFT JOIN test.known_numbers k ON a.callingpartyno = k.phone_number
  WHERE a.ts >= curdate()
  and(a.CALLINGPARTYNO in (select extension from test.ambition_users) OR a.finallycalledpartyno IN (select extension from test.ambition_users))


 ) x
 ORDER BY extension;") or die(mysqli_error( $conn2));




if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
$num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($result);
$headers = array();
while ($fieldinfo = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
    $headers[] = $fieldinfo->name;
}
$fp = fopen('test.csv', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
 fputcsv($fp, $headers);
 while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
}
    fclose($fp);
}


$file = "test.csv";
```

Comment: Try using `SUM(CASE...)`. Change the `'x'` and `''` to `1` and `0` respectively.

Comment: No it's not sql server, it is indeed mysql running in a PHP script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easiest to track the totals in PHP as you fetch the rows, and output a "totals" row each time the 'extension' column changes value (except before the first extension group).

```
$extension = null;
$totals = array_fill_keys($headers, 0);
$summableColumns = ['Received', 'ReceivedKnown', 'Outbound', 'outboundKnown', 'Missed', 'missedKnown'];
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($row['extension'] != $extension && $extension != null) {
        $totals['extension'] = "$extension totals:";
        fputcsv($fp, $totals);
        $totals = array_fill_keys($headers, 0);
        $extension = $row['extension'];
    }
    foreach ($summableColumns as $col) {
        if ($row[$col] == 'x') {
            $totals[$col]++;
        }
    }
    fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
}
```

The above code is not tested, but it should illustrate the idea.

Note I changed the fetch to use `MYSQLI_ASSOC`.

Also be careful to match the case of the column headers in the MySQL result set, because PHP associative arrays are case-sensitive.